# Как подписаться на все изменения контента?

Tags: поддержка, предложение, статус-отклонено

Пока на РЯ активность не слишком высокая, у меня есть (допустим) время обозреть все текущие изменения. Но нет технической возможности, система не сообщает о всех изменения - в лучшем случае только о вопросах и ответах, никак не комментариях и/или правках. А хотелось бы иметь представление, чем ресурс живет. На старом движке такая вещь достигалась сортировкой по времени **всех изменений**, включая малозначительные. А тут?

Comment: Можно конечно сделать бота, который будет обо всём сообщать.

Answer (score 2):

Опции отслеживания всего контента, к сожалению, нет, и ее реализация не запланирована.